# Input field reloads the page when I click to write text

Tags: magento2

When I click on the text area it immediately reloads the homepage. But it's working fine on the category page or on a sticky menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like overlapping of `<a>` tag, please check the design using browser inspect element